# jq - how to format pairs of keys and values, then iterate keys in json

Tags: json, linux, jq

Please help me, guys.
I have the following:

```
{
  "id": 88888,
  "name": "TESTING",
  "online": 1,
  "test_list": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "type": 34,
      "name": "Blabla",
      "used": 9870,
      "rate": 31768897891,
      "temp": 0,
      "percent": 100,
      "enabled": 0,
      "reset": 0,
      "temp": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": 23,
      "name": "AlbAlb",
      "used": 0865,
      "rate": 317681675432345678951,
      "temp": 1,
      "percent": 99,
      "enabled": 0,
      "reset": 0,
      "target": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": 98,
      "name": "TztS",
      "used": 65,
      "rate": 6324,
      "temp": 0,
      "percent": 80,
      "enabled": 0,
      "reset": 0,
      "target": 2
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "no": "123",
    "sw": "321",
    "version_detail": {
      "date": "2021-03-30",
      "build": "11",
      "cot": "dfgdfgd"
    }
  }
}
```

And i need to do the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "TESTING",
    "online": 1
  },
  {
    "id0": 0,
    "type0": 34,
    "name0": "Blabla",
    "rate0": 31768897891,
    "temp0": 0,
    "percent0": 100
    "id1": 1,
    "type1": 23,
    "name1": "AlbAlb",
    "rate1": 317681675432345670000,
    "temp1": 1,
    "percent1": 99
    "id2": 2,
    "type2": 98,
    "name2": "TztS",
    "rate2": 6324,
    "temp2": 0,
    "percent2": 80
  }
]
```

I want to join the information, what I need into blocks and then set the key numbering by id or iterate.
Will it be possible to somehow realised it using jq and man in one line?

After a long time, I managed to do only the following:

`jq '[. | {name,online}] + [.test_list[] | {id,type,name,rate,temp,percent} | with_entries(.key |= . + "0")]'`

I tried using map tool, but it doesn't work = (( Help Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reduce-free approach: it uses `with_entries` on an array to do the counting:

```
[ {name, online},
  (.test_list
   | with_entries(.key |= tostring
         | .key as $k
         | .value |= with_entries(.key += $k))
   | add
  )
]
```

Comment: Many thanks! It really works! Your second option is much clearer to me than the first))

Comment: I dared to shorten the final output format and add a little to your version to add a value pair filter. Thanx, bro =) I'm still a noob in json, so your solution helped me a lot, I will continue to learn!

Comment: It turned out to be the perfect solution for me:
{name, online} + ([.test_list[] | {id,type,name,rate,temp,percent}] | with_entries(.key |= tostring | .key as $k | .value |= (with_entries(.key |= . + $k)))
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bred_o_O - I'm intrigued that you found the solution with two `with_entries` to be clearer.  On the other hand, I have to wonder whether renaming the keys as you are doing here is really the best way to achieve whatever it is you're ultimately trying to do...

Comment: The default values available to me are provided by the api, so I cannot delete unneeded keys. And in order to filter the keys after jq, I will have to perform a lot of unnecessary actions, since this data is immediately loaded into the accounting system =)

Comment: Is `[.test_list[]]` the same as `.test_list` ?

Comment: @Philippe - In this case, yes. I was thinking of s.t. else ...

Answer (score 0):

The key is `with_entries`.  One possibility would be to use `reduce`:

```
[ {name, online},
  (.test_list
   | . as $in
   | reduce range(0; length) as $i ({}; . + ($in[$i] | with_entries(.key = "\(.key)\($i)")))
   )
]
```

Please note that your example output is not quite correct as JSON, and that with your example input, the above jq program produces slightly different results, but if you want to remove certain key-value pairs, you can easily do that, e.g. as a preliminary step in the pipeline.